# Insert into table on different server from trigger on table in another server for updating records from main system source

Tags: sql-server

This question maybe a matter of opinion, so I apologize if this falls under an opinionated question. To try to narrow the scope of the question I will be detailing what and why I am trying to do this.

I am using SQL Server 2014. The idea is that we have a main piece of software with a database hosted on one server which our HR department uses to add, update and delete company employees. I was brought in to design and develop new websites for specific work flows and I have tables in each of the websites I have been working on that store information about users. What I am trying to do is set triggers on the main system database tables that relate to employee information so that it inserts records into an employee update table which I then display to administrators to approve, in which case the changes will then be applied to the tables I have in my new website's database(s). The problem is that my databases are hosted on a different server than the one which hosts the main software database.

I have read through this article (https://www.sqlshack.com/querying-remote-data-sources-in-sql-server/) and I looked at the various ways to connect to a different server. The 3 ways I read about to accomplish this are as follows:
OPENDATASOURCE,
OPENROWSET,
LINKED SERVER

After reading through the article this one statement sticks out to me, 
"A SQL Server Linked Server is different from ad hoc queries in that ad hoc queries open a temporary connection with the remote server and close it, where the permanent linked server is always available for use."

As I only need to open the connection on triggers to do an insert I thought the ad hoc method would be best as I won't continually have a connection to the remote server. This is the first time I have ever attempted something like this, so I appreciate any constructive comments as to which method you would choose to do this and why, and if I am going about this in the wrong way, please suggest how you would do it and provide some references as I would be happy to read through articles or links suggested to help me in development.

Comment: So presumably you are going to create INSTEAD OF trigger here? I would just do this as an insert via linked server. Pretty straight forward and easy.

Comment: @SeanLange I want to set triggers on the relevant tables in the main system's database so that it inserts records into the update table I have created on my websites' server, so I am not sure what you mean by create INSTEAD OF triggers

Comment: You can connect sql server even oracle with linked server.

Comment: @MuratCanOĞUZHAN So, it would seem so far everyone is suggesting Linked Server as the correct way, and you are saying that Linked Server works well with different SQL types, so that seems like a valid reason to use that, do ad hoc methods not play well with other SQL types? example (SQL Server to Oracle)

Comment: Then you would create those triggers on those tables. Not sure what the confusion is. If the trigger is on the remote database and the destination table is on that same server there is no need for any remote anything in your trigger. As for an instead of trigger it would run your trigger instead of a normal insert. This sounds like you want to happen here. It wouldn't really update the account info, instead it would insert into another table with the new values that would need to be approved before the insert or update happened on the main table.

Comment: I think you might want to sit down with a flowchart and map this out. It sounds like you are getting a bit lost in the details. It can be tricky doing this kind of thing across multiple databases in multiple servers.

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you for your input, maybe some details are getting lost in translation, I want to use After Update, Delete, Insert on the main system database tables, as my update table is on another server. The main system should update, insert and delete with out preventing it from going through as this is done by HR people. But, I want this updated data to be stored in the update table in my websites's server so that admins of the websites I have developed can approve these changes before they are directly applied to my user/employee tables which the websites I have made use.

Comment: OK. Seems a little oddball to approve a change in the master table before displaying it in another system but whatever.

Comment: @SeanLange Agreed, but this is what the administrators want, so I am kind of stuck.

Comment: This is why I try to avoid making copies of data at all costs. This sounds like the beginning of a nightmarish project where the data is out of synch all the time. Maybe the admins will come to their senses and let you pull data directly from the master. :)

Comment: @SeanLange Yeah, maybe. But until then, it is what it is. Thank you very much for everyone's input. I appreciate it. I did vote for everyone's comments as useful and I will be upvoting the answers below. Once I decide between Service Broker and Linked Server I will mark one answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need create linked database and query this database with **four part naming** query.

you can create **linked database** use this syntax an `sp_addlinkedserver` like this:

```
sp_addlinkedserver [ @server= ] 'server' [ , [ @srvproduct= ] 'product_name' ] 
 [ , [ @provider= ] 'provider_name' ]
 [ , [ @datasrc= ] 'data_source' ] 
 [ , [ @location= ] 'location' ] 
 [ , [ @provstr= ] 'provider_string' ] 
 [ , [ @catalog= ] 'catalog' ]
```

and then in your `trigger` insert to this linked database table using four part naming query like this:

```
insert into [server].[database].[schema].[object] values(...)
```

more info about linked server and datatbase : [create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine)

Comment: @Ryan i hope this is helpful for you

Comment: I believe it will be, thanks again for your advice and example.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to have a hard coupling between the two systems, then consider SQL Server Service Broker.  Service Broker will allow you to asynchronously communicate between the two systems by passing messages back and forth.  For example, what happens if your application database is not available?  Should the insert on the source system fail?  If so, then a linked server query in a trigger is your easiest option.  If you want a more fault tolerant approach, then Service Broker can meet your needs.

Intro to Service Broker.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345108(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Thank you for the link and for the suggestion, I believe that I am going to go with the linked server approach for now, but I may use your suggestion in the future. I appreciate it and wish I could mark your post as an answer as well, but since I am going with the linked server approach, I will be marking Hasan's post as my accepted answer.